# What does $ \frac{m}{n} $ is fully reduced mean?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

I have been reading about Pythagorean triples from the wiki page link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

It says that a pythagorean triple consists of 3 positive integer's $ a, b, c $ such that $ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $.

Also if all the integers in a triple say $ a, b, c $ are relatively prime then the triplet is called Primitive Pythagorean triplet.

As I was reading more in this article it also described about generating  triple using Euclid's formula.

the formula is as follows :

$ a = m^2 - n^2, b = 2mn, c = m^2 + n^2 $ where $ m > n > 0 $

for any 2 values of $m$ and $n$ the above formula will give a Pythagorean Triple.

To get a Primitive Pythagorean triple $m$ and $n$ have to co - prime and not both odd.

I wanted to understand why this is formula is true and to understand the proof which is also given in the wiki page.

In the heading **Proof of Eucllid's formula** there comes a part where it says "As ${\displaystyle {\tfrac {m}{n}}} $ is fully reduced, $m$ and $n$ are coprime"

what does it mean by fully reduced there ?

Comment: Technically, it is $a=m^2-n^2$ and $c=m^2+n^2$ when the equation is $a^2+b^2=c^2.$

Comment: Use the the following. If $x^2=mn,$ where $\gcd(m,n)=1$, so there ate naturals $p$ and $q$ for which $m=p^2$ and $n=q^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means just what it says - that $m$ and $n$ are coprime, meaning that the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$ is 1, so you cannot simplify the fraction further.

If a fraction is not fully reduced, then we have $\text{gcd}(m, n) = k$, so we can factor out $k$ in both the numerator and the denominator, cancel it out and get the fully reduced form.

Comment: Note that this is usually called "reduced to lowest terms". +1 for you.

Comment: @MPW Thank you for telling me this! Not a native English speaker so not all terminology is familiar to me (especially things learned pre-university).

Answer (score 2):

It is well explained in this Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_fraction

A relevant excerpt:

> An **irreducible fraction** (or **fraction in lowest terms** or **reduced fraction**) is a fraction in which the numerator and denominator are integers that have no other common divisors than $1$ (and $-1$, when negative numbers are considered).
>
> ... A fraction that is **reducible** can be reduced by dividing both the numerator and denominator by a common factor. It can be **fully** reduced to lowest terms if both are divided by their greatest common divisor.

Comment: In the proof they transform the equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ to $\frac{(c + a)}{b} = \frac{b}{(c-a)}$ and then they equate to $ m/n $ is that the meaning of reduced ?

Comment: @RakendChauhan: the meaning of "reduced" is independent of the proof there. On the other hand, the proof says "Since ${\tfrac {(c+a)}{b}}$ is rational, we *set* it equal to ${\tfrac {m}{n}}$ **in lowest terms**". This gives the definition for $m$ and $n$, which is reason why the author says later that "As $\frac{m}{n}$ is fully reduced": because they are *defined* to be "in lowest terms", i.e., "fully reduced".

Comment: ohh thanks all this time I have been trying to relate reduced to that equation

Comment: @RakendChauhan: You are welcome!